# How to get a iframe from wordpress post content

Tags: wordpress

I have post with iframe like

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/71287888?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="900" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular.
```

In the above the i-frame need to be differentiate from th content. As i like only

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/71287888?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="900" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So, how can i get the video iframe for the content.

Comment: what do you mean by "get" - what are you doing with it?

Comment: Hello Alex, Thank you for interest in it. Actually i want to echo the iframe only from the content. Not any text

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the  the solution myself. 
Here's the code

```
$vcont = eevee_content(40);
$videoframe = explode("</iframe>",$vcont);
echo $videoframe[0]."</iframe>";
```

By the `eevee_content` function i was able to get the content. After that it explodes the string to an array and we get the iframe by using  `$videoframe[0]`